# ISPconfig openvz on debian 8

Tags: linux, debian, webserver, openvz, ispconfig

I have installed ISPconfig on my debian jessie server and it works well, but I want to use it as Virtual servers. I've choosed debian 8, beacuse I followed this tutorial:

https://github.com/servisys/ispconfig_setup

and as is it written in readme, this automated script will work with openvz only on Debian 8. But if I looked on linux packages, openvz is not installed. So my question is: can I install OpenVZ now? Even though I have ISPconfig installed? If yes exist any tutorial on internet for this? Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

No. If you want OpenVZ in this server with ISP, you must change kernel, which serve OpenVZ (2.6.x - 3.10).